# Error loading shared libraries on Windows

Tags: windows, protocol-buffers, bazel

I am on Windows 10 using msys.

Whenever I try to run protoc.exe for protobufs I get the following error.

`error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have checked with ldd

```
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffe998b0000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffe97c10000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffe972a0000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffe98900000)
```

All of these files exist and PATH is set to /c/Windows/SYSTEM32.

I am not sure what is going on here.

You can trigger this in bazel by trying to build any protobuf

`bazel build --compiler=mingw-gcc some_proto`

only in msys though.

Comment: Does it work in cmd.exe? Did you use a specific commandline? Just running it normally displays the help output for me.

Comment: Ahhh  you are right! It works in the command prompt if I set these PATH variables  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32 C:\msys64\usr\bin. I was using msys

Comment: How is this related to Bazel?

Comment: You can trigger it through bazel. Just try and build any protobuf with --compiler=mingw-gcc in msys

Comment: Recently I also meet this problem when installing `lua` with `msys2` following [this guide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua). I failed in `git-bash` but succeeded in `mingw32` (Here using `mingw32` is because I was using one 32-bit program for the compatibility). The problem is that `?` is difficult to debug. Then using `pwsh` it *shows which dll is missing* which is `D:\msys64\mingw32\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are two ways to fix this.

1. build through command prompt and change `PATH`
   to include

`C:\Windows\SYSTEM32`
`C:\msys64\usr\bin`

2. Through msys move the following files to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

- `ntdll.dll`
- `KERNEL32.DLL`
- `KERNELBASE.dll`
- `msvcrt.dll`